# JavaFX pack components

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

There is layout layout.fxml:

```
    <BorderPane fx:id="mainLayout" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
</BorderPane>
```

Further, in the method are in the loop 200 buttons:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @FXML
    private static BorderPane mainLayout;
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        this.stage = primaryStage;
        initMainLayout();
        initLoginForm();
    }

    private void initMainLayout() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/fxml/layout.fxml"));
        mainLayout = loader.load();
        mainLayout.getStyleClass().add("v-box");
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/style.css");
        stage.setTitle("ТЕМА ДИПЛОМА");
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void initMainForm() {
            final int HEIGHT = 39;
            final int WIDTH = 120;
            int count = 1;
            GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
            gridPane.getStyleClass().add("grid-pane");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.setText("Помещение №" + count++);
                    button.getStyleClass().add("button-all");
                    button.setOnAction(event -> new AdditionalController().buttonPressed(event));
                    gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(HEIGHT));
                    gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(WIDTH));
                    gridPane.add(button, i, j);
                }
            }
            mainLayout.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            mainLayout.getStyleClass().remove("v-box");
            mainLayout.getStyleClass().add("border-pane");
            mainLayout.setCenter(gridPane);
        }
```

CSS style buttons:

```
.button-all {
    -fx-background-color: #faffb0;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 9pt;
    -fx-text-fill: #054500;
    -fx-max-width: 89pt;
    -fx-max-height: 120pt;
}
```

Result resolution 1280:1024
[image]
All perfectly!!

But, 1024x768, It's bad:
[image]
Components is not pack(
How do I get when changing screen resolution, auto components?

Comment: What are you expecting? You are using absolute values for row and column constraints.

Comment: how to make a relative? or remake?

Comment: final int WIDTH = 94; final int HEIGHT = 26; // 1024x768                                   final int WIDTH = 120; final int HEIGHT = 39; // 1280x1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.setText("Помещение №" + count++);
            button.getStyleClass().add("button-all");
            button.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(gridPane.widthProperty(), 10));
            button.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(gridPane.heightProperty(), 20));
            //gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(HEIGHT));
            //gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(WIDTH));
            gridPane.add(button, i, j);
        }
    }
```

And get rid of `-fx-max-width`, `-fx-max-height` in css.

Comment: You did not remove either constraints or max height/width

Comment: Well, I can't see all you css styling and code. Actually, I even can't see where you are calling initMainForm(). Bindings works fine for me.

Comment: [Get new result](http://saveimg.ru/pictures/10-07-16/837c4e9f879997b06e4464956d5f8ac6.jpg)

Comment: add: mainLayout.getChildren().clear();  and result any resoluton!
[CLICK](http://saveimg.ru/pictures/10-07-16/ec46a70fd9056085d12eeb39ccdd5aae.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, I am very glad that there are people who help. My English is not perfect, but you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
-fx-min-width: 0pt;
-fx-min-height: 0pt;
```

to the end of your button stylesheet.

Comment: Added did not help, it's too easy!